# Arithmetic operations on periods of functions

Tags: functions

If $ f(x) $ has a period $ 7 $ and $ g(x) $ has a period $ 11 $, then the period of $ F(x) = f(x)g(\frac{x}{5}) - g(x)f(\frac{x}{3}) $.

Comment: Well., you should be able to tell what the period of $g(x/5)$ and $f(x/3)$ are.  Then, consider the least common multiple of the periods of all functions individually appearing and what that has to do with the period of $F(x)$.

Comment: What will be the period of f(x/3) and g(x/5)

Comment: $g(x)$ has period $11$ so $g(x/5)$ has period $5\times 11$.  In general, if $h(x)$ has period $p$ then $h(x/n)$ has period $p\cdot n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$F(x)=f(x)g(x/5)-g(x)f(x/3)$ has period $11\times 15\times 7 = 1155$

Note that $$ F(x+1155)=$$

$$ f(x+11\times 15\times 7 )g(x/5+11\times 3\times 7)-g(x+11\times 15\times 7)f(x/3+11\times 5\times 7) =$$

$$f(x)g(x/5)-g(x)f(x/3)=F(x)$$